# Injective but not surjective on an infinite set left inverse not unique.

Tags: functions

$f : \mathbb {N} \to \mathbb {N}$ be a function such that $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $

$f(n) =n+1$

i)Prove that f has at least two different left inverses.

ii)Find at least 2 of them.

I made this question/function up to help me understand the concept behind injectivity and surjectivity. I was trying to make a function that acted on a set back to that set that was injective but not surjective and find at least 2 left inverses.

Comment: ii) implies i), doesn't it? Hint: if $g\circ f = id$ then $g$ is only fixed on $\mathbb N + 1$. What is $g(1)$? (Assuming you start with 1 instead of 0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the function $g(n) = n-1$ if $n=1,2,3,\ldots$ and $g(0) = 10$. And then $h(n) = n-1$ for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$ and $h(0) = 20$? These are both left inverses.

Comment: i cant belive i understood how to do that with a finite set but not an infinite one...

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume $\Bbb N = \{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$, that is, that $\Bbb N$ starts with $1$ and not $0$; everything is easily modified if your $\Bbb N$ starts with $0$.

The key here is to identify what is *forced* to happen for any $g : \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ such that $g \circ f = \operatorname{id}_\Bbb N$, and what *leeway* such a function $g$ has.

Picking $n = 5$ as an arbitrary example, then because $g$ is a left-inverse of $f$, we know that 
$$5 = (g \circ f)(5) = g(f(5)) = g(6)$$

and so $g(6)$ cannot be anything but $5$: *because $6$ is in the image of $f$*, the value of $g(6)$ is completely determined.

More generally,

- $g$ is *forced* to take particular values on all of $\operatorname{im}(f) = \{2, 3, 4, \ldots\}$. Consequently,
- we are free to define the value of $g$ on $\Bbb N \setminus \operatorname{im}(f) = \{1\}$ in any way we'd like.

*This* is where our leeway is to be found.